# Prove that this splitting field has degree 4 over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> If $m$ and $n$ are distinct square-free positive integers greater than $1$, show that the splitting field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{m}, \sqrt{n})$ of $(X^2-m)(X^2-n)$ has degree 4 over $\Bbb{Q}$.

**Proof**

$X^2 - m \in \Bbb{Q}$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion since it's square free. So $[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{m}: \Bbb{Q}] =2$. Since $m \not= n$, $\sqrt{m}$ cannot be a root of $x^2 - n$. So $[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{m}, \sqrt{n}): \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})] \geq 2$. However, since $x^2-n$ is irreducible by Eisenstein $[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{m}, \sqrt{n}): \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})] = 2$.

Do you think my proof is correct?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The degree is certainly $\le 4$. You have not shown it is not $2$. Need to show nothing in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ is a root of $x^2-n$, not just $\sqrt{m}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Since n is square free, $\sqrt{n}$ is an irrational number. If we assume that $\sqrt{m}$ is a root of $x^2-n$, then $(\sqrt{m})^2 - n = 0 \implies m=n$, contradiction. So $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{m}, \sqrt{n})$ is not the same as $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ and $[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{m}, \sqrt{n}): \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})] \not= 1$. Is that correct?

Comment: It does not solve the problem. Unless you find another way to sneak around it, you need to show that $\sqrt{n}$ cannot be expressed as $\alpha +\beta\sqrt{m}$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are rational. This is not hard to do.

Comment: $x^2-n$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$, but I don't think it's by Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: Wow! Eisenstein's criterion to show that a quadratic $X^2-m$ with square-free $m$ is irreducible.  I think  I detect a symptom of excessive education here.

Comment: @Rose: Well, $m\ne -1$, and $m$ is square-free, so Eisenstein's Criterion does technically work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete the proof along your lines, we need to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})\ne \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$. We give a number-theoretically oriented argument.

It is enough to show that there do not exist integers $a$, $b$, and $c$, with $c\ne 0$, such that $\sqrt{n}=\frac{a+b\sqrt{m}}{c}$.

Suppose to the contrary that there are such integers. So $c\sqrt{n}=a+b\sqrt{m}$.

It is clear that $b$ cannot be $0$. If $a=0$, we have $c^2n=b^2m$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $b$ and $c$ are relatively prime. But then $b^2$ and $c^2$ are relatively prime, so $c^2$ divides $m$. Since $m$ is square-free, this is only possible if $c^2=1$. Similarly, $b^2=1$. It follows that $m=n$, contradicting the fact that $m\ne n$,

So we have $c\sqrt{n}=a+b\sqrt{m}$, where neither $a$ nor $b$ is equal to $0$. By squaring both sides, we conclude that $2ab\sqrt{m}$ is rational, which is not true.

Comment: why $c^2$ divides m?

Comment: In general, if $x$ divides $st$, and $x$ and $s$ are relatively prime, then $x$ divides $t$. This is sometimes called Euclid's Lemma. A proof is given early in any first number theory course. Here goes. f $x$ and $s$ are relatively prime, there exist integers $u$ and $v$ such that $ux+vs=1$ (Bezout). Multiply by $t$. We get $tux+tvs=t$. Both terms on the left are divisible by $x$, so $x$ divides $t$.